# Could not run hg on ubuntu terminal

Tags: python, ubuntu, mercurial, pip, tortoisehg

I installed mercurial using sudo apt-get install mercurial and it installed properly. But when I run any hg command I get the **following Error Message**-

> abort: couldn't find mercurial libraries in [/home/yashu/bin
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/networkx-2.0.dev_20150923032326-py3.4.egg
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/decorator-4.0.2-py3.4.egg
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Cython-0.23.2-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pgmpy-0.1.0-py3.4.egg
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-1.2.1-py3.4.egg
>   /usr/lib/python3.4 /usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
>   /usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
>   /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages] (check your install and PYTHONPATH)

then I tried installing it with pip and it again installed successfully but on runnning any hg command I get the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have more than 1 mercurial installed. The one you `apt-get install` will probably be `/usr/bin/hg`. Try running

```
which -a hg
```

to find all your hg binaries in your `$PATH`.

Or try running `/usr/bin/hg` instead of just `hg`.

Comment: I ran which -a hg but i got this - /home/yashu/bin/hg and
/usr/local/bin/hg

Comment: I tried doing /home/yashu/bin/hg but get the same error

Comment: Try running /usr/local/bin/hg in that case. Maybe that one works? Strange though, that there is no /usr/bin/hg. Are you sure the apt-get install went ok?

Comment: yes this one is working. thanks. how can i uninstall  the other mercurial?

Comment: `apt-get install mercurial` should really install a `/usr/bin/hg`. If that does not exist, try reinstalling the mercurial package. If it does exist, then probably your `$PATH` does not include `/usr/bin/` but that would be crazy.

Comment: `pip uninstall mercurial` ?  Hard to say because you seem to have mercurials installed from different sources...

Comment: The `hg` in your `/home/yashu/bin` must have been installed by you manually. Both `apt-get` and `pip` do not install there. You should probably manually remove it using `rm`.  Please remember to accept the answer if this helped you.

Comment: hey here is what I did, i did pip2 uninstall mercurial then removed /home/yashu/bin/hg manually. I then used sudo apt-get install mercurial. Now which -a hg shows the path /usr/bin/hg. Problem solved. I can use hg command now. Thanks again.